# Using Loop with Raster Calculator in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, anaconda

I am trying to loop through multiple rasters and extract cells that are above 0.1 The code I am trying to use is:

```
import arcpy 
arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Spatial')
arcpy.env.workspace=r'F:\Sheyenne\Atmospherically Corrected Landsat\Indices\Main\NDWI\main_master'
#pathway to all rasters in workspace directory
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters('*.tif*')
for raster in rasters:
     #give new file a name
     outraster = raster.replace('.tif','_water.tif')
     arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa("""raster >= 0.1""",outraster)
print('Done Processing')
```

For some reason I can't copy and paste the error (python actually shuts down when I run this code) but here is a screen shot of part of it.

[image]

EDIT:
My parameters have changed and I now need everything >=-0.4 and but !=0.00.  I am trying to use:

```
import arcpy 
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Spatial')
arcpy.env.workspace=r'D:\Sheyenne\Atmospherically Corrected Landsat\Indices\Main\NDWI\main_master'
#pathway to all rasters in workspace directory
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters('*.tif*')
for raster in rasters:
    #Save temp raster to disk with new name
    ras = Raster(raster)
    outraster = Con(ras >= -0.4 & ras !=0.00, ras)
    outraster.save(raster.replace('.tif','_water.tif'))
print('Done Processing')
```

but this returns:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a raster is ambiguous. Invalid use of raster with Boolean operator or function. Check the use of parentheses where applicable.
```

EDIT:

I think I just needed to change this line:

```
 outraster = Con((ras >= -0.4) & (ras !=0.00), ras)
```

Comment: Take a chance to add try:
    "CODE"
except Exception, e:
    print e . This will allow You to detect error

Comment: nah, wasn't anaconda it always works fine.  Was the reason listed below.

Comment: @spotter yes you need brackets around your expressions `outraster = Con((ras >= -0.4) & (ras !=0.00), ras)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the ArcGIS Help:

> The Raster Calculator tool is intended for use in the ArcGIS Desktop application only as a GP tool dialog box or in ModelBuilder. It is not intended for use in scripting and is not available in the ArcPy Spatial Analyst module.

You should use `arcpy.sa` map algebra instead:

```
import arcpy 
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Spatial')
arcpy.env.workspace=r'F:\Sheyenne\Atmospherically Corrected Landsat\Indices\Main\NDWI\main_master'
#pathway to all rasters in workspace directory
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters('*.tif*')
for raster in rasters:
    outraster = Raster(raster) >= 0.1
    #Save temp raster to disk with new name
    outraster.save(raster.replace('.tif','_water.tif'))
print('Done Processing')
```

Note: both your original expression and the map algebra version above will not extract the values of the cells, but output a 1 where the condition is met and 0 otherwise. If you want the actual cell values, you need to use the Con function:

```
ras = Raster(raster)
outraster = Con(ras >= 0.1, ras)
```

You may be having issues with the spaces in your path, it would be better to remove the spaces, but you could also try setting the scratch workspace to a folder without spaces, i.e `arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = r'C:\Temp'`

Comment: I see, was not aware of that, this seems to work though thanks!

Comment: also, how would I edit it this to say everything >= 0.1, but !=0?  would it just be `>= 0.1, !=0`

Comment: well, 0.0 for me is actually no data, and my parameters  have changes since initial post so I want everything >=-0.4, but != 0.00 but seems like it will just be `raster >=-0.4 & raster !=0.00`

Comment: forgive me but new to all this, I added an edit to show you what I'm attempting