# arcpy add rasters using raster calculator

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, error-000732, error-999998

what I want to do is add multiple raster layers stored in FGDB together using the raster calculator in arcpy

To start off I have seen this question [Using Loop with Raster Calculator in ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163368/using-loop-with-raster-calculator-in-arcpy)

this is what it would look like in arcgis raster calculator

```
'remap1'+'remap2'+'remap3'+'remap4'+'remap5'+'remap6'+'remap7'+'remap8'+'remap9'+'remap10'+'remap11'+'remap12'+'remap13'+'remap14'+'remap15'+'remap16'+'remap17'+'remap18'+'remap19'+'remap20'+'remap21'+'remap22'+'remap23'+'remap24'+'remap25'+'remap26'+'remap27'+'remap28'+'remap29'+'remap30'+'remap31'
```

now in Python

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.env.workspace=env
reclass1 = '+'.join(["Raster("+"r'{}'".format(x)+")" for x in arcpy.ListRasters() if x[:5]=='remap' if int(x[5:]) < 14 ])
print reclass1
```

which prints out to

```
 Raster(r'remap1')+Raster(r'remap2')+Raster(r'remap3')+Raster(r'remap4')+Raster(r'remap5')+Raster(r'remap6')+Raster(r'remap7')+Raster(r'remap8')+Raster(r'remap9')+Raster(r'remap10')+Raster(r'remap11')+Raster(r'remap12')+Raster(r'remap13')
```

now how do I execute this command and save it to new Raster file?

```
b=Raster(reclass1)
b.save("blah")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "R:\Data\LUCZ_2017\ConservationPriorityAreas\cons.py", line 36, in <module>
    Raster_Calculator(env2)
  File "R:\Data\LUCZ_2017\ConservationPriorityAreas\cons.py", line 34, in Raster_Calculator
    b=Raster(reclass1)
RuntimeError: ERROR 000732: Input Raster: Dataset Raster(r'remap1')+Raster(r'remap2')+Raster(r'remap3')+Raster(r'remap4')+Raster(r'remap5')+Raster(r'remap6')+Raster(r'remap7')+Raster(r'remap8')+Raster(r'remap9')+Raster(r'remap10')+Raster(r'remap11')+Raster(r'remap12')+Raster(r'remap13') does not exist or is not supported
```

**update**

```
reclass1 = [Raster(x) for x in arcpy.ListRasters() if x[:5]=='remap' if int(x[5:]) < 14 ]
print reclass1

print sum(reclass1)
```

use the regular python sum tool??

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\abid.py", line 19, in <module>
    print sum(reclass1)
RuntimeError: ERROR 999998: Unexpected Error.
```

Comment: `reclass1` is a string: `'Raster(r'remap1')+Raster(r'remap2')...'` That is probably why it is not working

Comment: okay that is helpful but doesn't completely answer my question

Comment: I doubt it is possible to build an expression like that. You would need to "unpack" it. Use cell statistics with sum instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [Cell Statistics tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/cell-statistics.htm), just look at the code sample at the bottom of the page. You've cracked the code to create a list of raster names just feed that into the tool.

Comment: okay I will give this a try

Comment: nice, thanks. Rasters in python is a bit tricky tbh